# Read a value from page loaded in DotNetBrowser

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I'm trying to write some values to a login form, submit it, and then grab some data on the results page using DotNetBrowser in a c# project, but for some reason, I cannot seem to get at the resulting text.

Filling and submitting the form works fine, but once the results come back, I would expect this to work similarly to get a value from the results page, but it does not:

`var msg = browser.ExecuteJavaScriptAndReturnValue("$('table.MyTable').outerHTML").ToString();`

I've been looking at a documentation page to find the answer, but the code is different enough that I'm not sure how to implement it:
https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000109868-calling-javascript-from-net

What am I missing, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this code did not work for me originally was due to confusion in the way that the events are defined in the example app I was using as a starting point. In that app, the events are all generated dynamically within the load events of objects, and this made it unclear to me where and when to fire my custom code additions. As a result, my code was being fired before the page finished loading, even though I made some efforts to try and allow it to do just that.

For anyone else working on learning DotNetBrowser, I recommend you do what I did to resolve this, and learn how the objects work: Install the control into Visual Studio and use early binding for the events, as this makes it a lot easier to setup test apps and observe the order of events, and the code needed for each of those events without the added complications of dynamically generating those event signatures.